# Calling Div images in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I want to pass all the images that are inside `<div id="supersized"></div>` to jquery supersized plugin.

My current implementation is below, but this doesnt work.

**JQUERY Code**

```
    $(function(){
                $.fn.supersized.options = {  
                    startwidth: 640,  
                    startheight: 480,
                    vertical_center: 1,
                    slideshow: 1,
                    navigation: 1,
                    thumbnail_navigation: 1,
                    transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-               slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
                    pause_hover: 0,
                    slide_counter: 1,
                    slide_captions: 1,
                    slide_interval: 3000,
                    slides : [

  {image : 'slides/tower.jpg', title : 'City Clock Tower'},
  {image : 'slides/fence.jpg', title : 'Canal Park Fence'},  
  {image : 'slides/tracks.jpg', title : 'Old Train Tracks'}
                    ]
                };
                $('#supersized').supersized(); 
            });
```

**Jsp code**

```
<div id="supersized">



<IMG SRC="../img/nature/xyz.jpg'" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150" BORDER="0" ALT="">  


<IMG SRC="../img/nature/asaz.jpg'" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150" BORDER="0" ALT="">  


<IMG SRC="../img/nature/sun.jpg'" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150" BORDER="0" ALT="">  


</div>
```

Please help me out

Comment: To call the image you need to know its number.

Comment: I want to call all the images that inside div tag. I'm using it for slideshow.

Comment: as a sidenote you should remove all those presentational attributes and move border, height and width in the css

Comment: @Akshay OK. But what do you mean by "call"? You need to pass them to `supersized` plugin or just select?

Comment: @VisioN Sorry, i mean pass the images to supersized plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#supersized img').supersized();
```

if I get you well.

Comment: I want to get all the images inside  slides : [
 div images
                    ]

Comment: wait, wait. once again - you want to take images from `slides` array and put them into `#supersized` div? or what?

Comment: i want all the images to slide by passing it to slides:[xyz.jpg,ss.jpg,..etc]. just like slide show. But image should taken from <div id="supersized"> <img xyz.jpg> <img ss.jpg>.. etc</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#supersized img').each(function(){
  alert( "src is : " + $(this).attr('src') );
});
```

lops through the collection of images and alerts the src code